# Getting Junk Characters while reading AppName programmatically on Android

Tags: android, contextmenu

My Sample code to get the AppName.

```
public static String getApplicationName(Context mContext) {
    String applicationName = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    if (applicationName != null) {
        return applicationName;
    } else { 
        return applicationName;
    }
}
```

values folder under res

```
<string name="app_name">Test App Name</string>
```

Note: some times, I am receiving Junk characters for AppName

> Ex: à¤¬à¤¾à¤°à¤•à¥‹à¤¡ à¤¸à¥&#14

Please help to come out from this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated, but the `if` statement is pretty useless.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you tried the below code?

```
int stringId = this.getApplicationInfo().labelRes;
String appName = this.getString(stringId);
Log.e(TAG, appName);
```